# Ruby on Rails - Devise Omniauth - Coinbase Strategy - Pass account parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, coinbase-api

[Coinbase Connect (OAuth2)](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/permissions) allows a user to grant access to an App either for a specific account or for all accounts owned by the user.

The choice depends on the account parameter on OAuth2 authorization URL (default value = `select` to grant access to a single account).

I need to use `account=all`

Anyone know where I can set this in Devise ?

I've tried :

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.omniauth :coinbase, ENV['COINBASE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['COINBASE_SECRET_ID'], scope: 'wallet:user:email wallet:accounts:read wallet:payment-methods:read wallet:sells:create wallet:withdrawals:create', account: :all
```

But this didn't change the authorization URL

And then I tried adding the parameter in the omniauth_authorize_path in the `app/views/pages/profile.html.erb`

```
        <button class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center pr-4 coinbase-btn">
          <%= image_tag 'logo-coinbase-white.svg', class: "coinbase-logo" %>
          <%- User.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
            <%= link_to "Connect your #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)} Wallet",
            omniauth_authorize_path(current_user, provider, account: 'all') %>
          <% end %>
        </button>
```

(This is the page where I want users to link their coinbase account with their account on my app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in to the `omniauth-coinbase` gem that I'm using , I figured the list of options we can pass is defined [here](https://github.com/coinbase/omniauth-coinbase/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/coinbase.rb) at line 30 :

Line 30 : `option :authorize_options, [:scope, :meta]`

This line specifies which options we can use.

I thus forked the gem and added :account to the list of authorized options

Then I was able to pass it in my `devise.rb`

```
config.omniauth :coinbase, 
                ENV['COINBASE_CLIENT_ID'],
                ENV['COINBASE_SECRET_ID'],
                scope: 'wallet:user:email wallet:accounts:read wallet:payment-methods:read wallet:sells:create wallet:withdrawals:create',
                account: 'all'
```